# Cannot change response element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I can excess a td element from AJAX response but can't change it.

```
$('#addjob').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: 'invoicelist.php',
        success: function(response){
            $('#forajax').append(response);
            $(response).find('.heading').html();
        }
    });
});
```

this code works well and selects the text from the `<td class='heading'>123</td>` but if I want to change this 123 result I write `$(response).find('.heading').html('456');` but it doesnt really change anything.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing the raw HTML into your `#forajax` container, then creating a new jQuery object with the contents of `response`. Any changes to the new object will be discarded; they have nothing to do with the HTML you wrote.

Get the object first, modify it, then append:

```
// create a jQuery object wrapping the returned HTML
var r = $(response);

// update the contents of our new object
r.find('.heading').html('456');

// add the new, updated object to our container
r.appendTo('#forajax');
```

Comment: this worked really nice... but I couldn't understand why. can you please describe it once more for me?

Comment: added comments within

Answer (score 0):

Change it, then append. That content isn't linked to that variable:

```
$(response).find('.heading').html('456');
$('#forajax').append(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing in repsonse will change in the response text but not the appended DOM object. so instead search for dom element where u appended and do there

```
$('#addjob').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'invoicelist.php',
        success: function(response){
            $( '#forajax' ).append(response);
            $( '#forajax' ).find('.heading').html( '456' );
        }
     });   
});
```